# Correctly binding click event to a function using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

As mentioned, I'm trying to bind clicking the 'a' tags on my page to my handleClickTag() function, but am struggling to implement the .on() method to bind the function and 'a' tag. I'm not sure if bind() would be more appropriate. Hope this makes sense!

```js
a.data('tagId', tag.id); //save info inside html element
$(a).on('click', handleClickTag(a)); //bind click event of the "a" tag to the "handleClickTag" function - need help here

//code above contained inside forEach loop

function handleClickTag (event) {
 var link = $(event.target);
 
 var tagId = link.data('tagId');//would like to retrieve data from the tagId variable

 //---continue function after data is correctly retrieved
 }
```

Comment: $(a).on('click', handleClickTag(a)); => $(a).on('click', handleClickTag);  should do the trick. also you might want to use preventDefault(); in your handler so that the default behavior of the anchor tag isn't executed, and only what is defined in your handler is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass argument to the function you can wrap the function call inside of an anonymous function:

```
$(a).on('click', function(){ handleClickTag(a); });
```

Though I think you do not need to pass the argument here, Simply the following should work:

```
$(a).on('click', handleClickTag);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help  - the second option works. I was simply unnecessarily adding the argument!